# sudo apt-get install apache2 on ec2 instace type: ami-e0efab88 fails

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've created an ec2 instance debian-wheezy-amd64-hvm-2015-01-28-ebs (ami-e0efab88)

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id myimage --security-group-ids mysecuritygroup --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name mykey --query 'Instances[0].InstanceId'
```

then connected to it and tried to install apache2 on it

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

got the following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apache2
```

**Note:** creating a GCE instance `debian-7-wheezy-v20131014` and running the same command works perfectly

What am I missing?

Comment: did you run `apt-get update` before you install apache ?

Comment: good, making an answer then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments, the rule is always to run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

before installing any software with apt-get package